# Reordering (deleting/changing order) columns of data in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two large data sets and I am attempting to reformat the older data set to put the questions in the same order as the newer data set (so that I can easily perform t-tests on each identical question to track significant changes over the 2 years between data sets). The new version both deleted and added questions when changing from the old version.

The way I've been attempting to do this, R keeps crashing due to, as best I can figure, vectors being too large. I'm not sure how they are getting to be this large, however! Below is what I am doing:

Both data sets have the same format. The original sets are 415 for the new and 418 for the old. I want to match the first approximately 158 colums of the new data set to the old. Each data set has column names which are q1-q415 and the data in each column is numerical 1-5 or NA. There are approximately 100 answers per question/column, the old data set has more respondants (140 rows in old vs 114 rows in new). An example is below (but keep in mind there are over 400 columns in the full set and over 100 rows!)

The following is an example of what data.old looks like. data.new looks the same only data.new has more Rows of number/na answers. Here I show questions 1 through 20 and the first 10 rows.
data.old = 418 columns (q1 though q418) x 140 rows
data.new = 415 columns (q1 through q415) x 114 rows
I need to match the first 170 COLUMNS of data.old to the first 157 COLUMNS of data.new
To do this, I will be deleting 17 columns from data.old (questions that were in the data.old questionnaire and deleted from the data.new questionnaire) but also adding 7 new columns to data.old (which will contain NAs... place holders for where data.new had new questions introducted that did not exist in data.old questionnaire)

```
    >data.old
    q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 q10 q11 q12 q13 q14 q15 q16 q17 q18 q19 q20
    1  3  4  3  3  5  4  1  NA  4  NA  1   2    NA  5   4  3    2   3   1
    3  4  5  2  2  4  NA 1   3  2  5   2   NA   3   2   1  4    3   2   NA
    2  NA 2  3  2  1  4  3   5  1  2   3   4    3   NA  NA 2    1   2   5
    1  2  4  1  2  5  2  3   2  1  3   NA  NA   2   1   5  5    NA  2   3
    4  3  NA 2  1  NA 3  4   2  2  1   4   5    5   NA  3  2    3   4   1
    5  2  1  5  3  2  3  3  NA  2  1   5   4    3   4   5  3    NA  2   NA
    NA 2  4  1  5  5  NA NA  2  NA 1   3   3    3   4   4  5    5   3   1
    4  5  4  5  5  4  3  4   3  2  5   NA  2    NA  2   3  5    4   5   4
    2  2  3  4  1  5  5  3  NA  2  1   3   5    4   NA  2  3    4   3   2
    2  1  5  3  NA 2  3  NA  4  5  5   3   2    NA  2   3  1    3   2   4
```

So in the new set, some of the questions were deleted, some new ones were added, and some changed order, so I went through and created subsets of old data in the order that I would need to combine them again to match the new dataset. When a question does not exist in the old data set, I want to use the question in the new data set so that I can (theoretically) perform my t-tests in a big loop.

```
    dataold.set1 <- dataold[1:16]
    dataold.set2 <- dataold[18:19]
    dataold.set3 <- dataold[21:23]
    dataold.set4 <- dataold[25:26]
    dataold.set5 <- dataold[30:33]
    dataold.set6 <- dataold[35:36]
    dataold.set7 <- dataold[38:39]
    dataold.set8 <- dataold[41:42]
    dataold.set9 <- dataold[44]
    dataold.set10 <- dataold[46:47]
    dataold.set11 <- dataold[49:54]
    dataold.set12 <- datanew[43:49]
    dataold.set13 <- dataold[62:85]
    dataold.set14 <- dataold[87:90]
    dataold.set15 <- datanew[78]
    dataold.set16 <- dataold[91:142]
    dataold.set17 <- dataold[149:161]
    dataold.set18 <- dataold[55:61]
    dataold.set19 <- dataold[163:170]
```

I then was attempting to put the columns back together into one set
I tried both

```
    dataold.adjust <- merge(dataold.set1, dataold.set2)
    dataold.adjust <- merge(dataold.adjust, dataold.set3)
    dataold.adjust <- merge(dataold.adjust, dataold.set4)
```

and I also tried

```
    dataold.adjust <- cbind(dataold.set1, dataold.set2, dataold.set3)
```

However, every time I try to perform these functions, R freezes, then crashes. I managed to get it to display an error once, and it said it could not work with a vector of 10 Mb, and then I got multiple errors involving over 1000 Mb vectors. I'm not really sure how my vectors are that large, when this is crashing out by set 3, which is only 23 columns of data in a table, and the data sets I'm normally using are over 400 columns in length.

Is there another way to do this that won't cause my program to crash and have memory issues (and won't require me typing out the column names of over 100 columns), or is there some element of code here that I am missing where I'm getting a memory sink? I've been attempting to trouble shoot it and have spent an hour dealing with R crashing without any luck figuring out how to make this work.

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making tons of unnecessary copies of your data and then you're growing the final object (`dataold.adjust`).  You just need a vector that orders the columns correctly:

```
cols1 <- c(1:16,18:19,21:23,25:26,30:33,35:36,38:39,41:42,44,46:47,49:54)
cols2 <- c(62:85,87:90)
cols3 <- c(91:142,149:161,55:61,163:170)
# merge old / new data by row and add NA for unmatched rows
dataold.adjust <- merge(data.old[,c(cols1,cols2,cols3)],
  data.new[,c(43:49,78)], by="row.names", all=TRUE)
# put columns in desired order
dataold.adjust <- dataold.adjust[,c(1:length(cols1),  # 1st cols from dataold
  ncol(dataold.adjust)-length(43:49):1,               # 1st cols from datanew
  (length(cols1)+1):length(cols2),                    # 2nd cols from dataold
  ncol(dataold.adjust),                               # 2nd cols from datanew
  (length(cols1)+length(cols2)+1):length(cols3))]     # 3rd cols from dataold
```

The last part is an absolute kludge, but I've hit my self-imposed time limit for SO today. :)

Comment: That looks like it will be massively more effective and efficient (and I knew there must be a better way, but with my limited knowledge of R my attempt was the best I could do) However - when I use this code I get `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 140, 114` 
Is there a way to force the rows to be different? I know my new data set has less rows than my old (or can I populate the last 30ish rows with <NA>)

Comment: Do `data.old` and `data.new` have the same number of rows?  What type of object are they (data.frame or matrix)?

Comment: They have a different number of rows (I believe I said that in my original question, but I do know I wrote a lot and that might have been missed) data.old = 140 rows and data.new = 114 rows. They are both data.frames (I read them in from a .csv file using read.table). All these columns I'm reordering right now are class int, obviously, but when I originally imported the data, the original file had string answers in the last 50 or so columns - so I either need to have the new table allow different number of rows, or if its possible to populate new rows 115->140 in data.new with <NA>

Comment: @Aibhilin: see my edit.  The last part could certainly be more elegant.  Perhaps if you post a (small!) sample of your two data sets, someone could come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: Well, that loaded everything without errors, but I don't really follow the code very well! I looked at the new data it created, however, and I'm a little confused as it where some of the names are coming from (probably having to do with the fact that I do not understand the code particularly well) but it seems like it might be duplicating some columns in a strange way... my data for this section in data.old is number q1 - q170 (and the new data set is q1-q158, so that's approximately how many columns I should be ending up with)) but I thought that the column headers would be preserved

Comment: but when I looked at `head(dataold.adjust)` I saw `row.names Row.names q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 q10 q11 q12 q13 q14 q15 q16 q18 q19 q21 q22 q23 q25 q26 q30 q31 q32 q33 q35 q36 q38 q39 q41 q42 q44.x q46.x q47.x q49.x q50 q51 q52 q53 q43 q44.y q45 q46.y q47.y q48 q49.y q54 q53.1 q52.1 q51.1 q50.1 q49.x.1 q47.x.1 q46.x.1 q44.x.1 q42.1 q41.1 q39.1 q38.1 q36.1 q35.1 q33.1 q78.y q90 q91 q92 q93 q94 q95 q96 q97 q98 q99` I'm not sure whether things have gone together correctly when it's giving me column names such as q49.x.1... is there a part of the code that is changing these column names?

Comment: I do appreciate the help you have been providing, by the way! I'm just a dummy when it comes to R coding (my experience in the past has been no more than import 1 data set, run anova, nothing complex like I need to do in my current job) Hopefully I can look at this from a fresh mindset for tomorrows workday :)

Comment: I had a chance to examine this at work this morning, and the code is not putting things in the right order, as far as I can tell. I looked at `head(dataold.adjust)` and the first 5 columns did not match up with the first 5 columns of `head(data.old)`, and they should be the same as the first 16 columns of `dataold.adjust` are the same as the first 16 columsn of `data.old`. I looked into the cols variables to ensure they were matching, and `head(data.old[cols1])` correctly matches the first 16 lines of `head9data.old` alone, so something in the merge/reordering is not working

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you provided some sample data.  Otherwise I have to imagine what your data are like, make code suggestions, then you try them and report back and I have to use your descriptions to re-imagine what your data are like... Comments aren't the place for extended discussions; use chat for that.

Comment: I'd move the discussion to chat but it says I don't have enough reputation for that. I provided an example of what my data looks like in my original comment but in a 4x4... it's hard to provide a sample when I have 150 columns by 140 rows. I will edit the original post with a larger sample set.

Comment: using the larger data set I have now provided, an example of the output that your code gave (the comment I have 5 above this) would be giving something like `q1 q2 q3 q4 q5.x q6.x q4.y q5.y q8 q9 q10.1 q11.1 q12.1 q7.x.1 q8.x.1 q16 q17 q18 q19 q20` So after merging the data columns, the column headers are not being preserved after the merge. They are duplicating, adding additional letters (x and y) and decimals (.1) that I cannot find a pattern with. Also, instead of the first column, q1, looking identical to original data (above), it would contain the values (ex) `>q1 >NA 4 2 3 1 3 2 5 NA 2`

Comment: I managed to get it to work properly by using the original cbind notation (that didn't work due to the different row length of data.old and data.new). I created a new .csv file that was just dummy columns of NAs of the appropriate length and used those instead of the data.new columns. It wasn't crucial that the data be data.news, just needed a filler column so that I could loop my tests. Thanks for all your help, I wouldn't have known how to do it at all without your original answer!