# Shorting the columns of data frame under a specific group

Tags: r

I have a data frame from which the columns has this format:

```
name             stock1 stock2 value1 value2
stoc_from_csv    Google Yahoo   50      21
stock up to date Opel   Tayoota 42      44
```

How can I reshape the column to have all with 1 the one next to other, same for 2 etc. An example of output:

```
    name             stock1 value1 stock2 value2
    stoc_from_csv    Google 50      Yahoo   21
    stock up to date Opel   42      Tayoota 44
```

Comment: Maybe `df[, c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5)]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reordering (deleting/changing order) columns of data in data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670513/reordering-deleting-changing-order-columns-of-data-in-data-frame) or of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205729/change-the-order-of-a-column) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788026/change-the-order-of-columns), among others...

Comment: @Cath The links you showed for dupe are not specific to here.  Having said that I don't have any problem in closing this (if it is the specific kind).

Comment: @Cath How is that dupe link answering this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to remove the non-numeric characters from the column names (except the first - which don't have any numeric part) using `sub`, convert the `character` output to `numeric`, `order` it and use that as numeric index to rearrange the columns.

```
df1[c(1, order(as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '', names(df1)[-1])))+1L)]
#                 name stock1 value1  stock2 value2
#1    stoc_from_csv Google     50   Yahoo     21
#2 stock up to date   Opel     42 Tayoota     44
```

Or a variant of the above would be using `stri_order` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
df1[stri_order(sub('\\D+', '', names(df)),
                 opts = list(numeric = TRUE))]
```

(contributed by @David Arenburg)

---

Or another option would be to convert the column names to a `matrix` (depends on whether the names are arranged in the sequence)

```
df1[c('name',c(matrix(names(df1)[-1], 
              ncol= (ncol(df1)-1)/2, byrow=TRUE)))]
```

Comment: Also, (not sure if any better) `df[stringi::stri_order(sub('\\D+', '', names(df)), opts = list(numeric = TRUE))]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I receive this error `Error in name(df1) : invalid 'description' argument`. Could it be a problem having different names for columns like stock_1 stock_value_1

Comment: @Berbery It could be a problem with different names.  My solution was considering the pattern you showed in the example.

Comment: @akrun Could I ask in order to understand how you configure at the specific case?

Comment: @Berbery If you could update the post with a new example that mimics the original dataset and expected output, I can take a look.  It's too late here, but I will look into it in the morning.